# Server 2016 Session time limits for specific users

Tags: time, session

I am aware you can set session time limits for all idle/disconnected users on Server 2012/2016 etc, however I was wondering if there is a way to end disconnected/idle session only for some users and not all? Reason being, we'd love to have the policy in place for most users however we need a single user to remain logged in and disconnected running an app in the background that is required, and thus cannot be affected by time limits.

Answer (score 1):

If you set your desired session time limits under User Configuration in a GPO then you can use Security Filtering on the GPO to apply it to only those users who you want to be affected by the time limits.